# "Don't ask again before sending requests to" checked or not

Tags: facebook-graph-api, request, facebook-fql, fbjs

I tried this using "Test user" and random friend , it seems "Test user"  continue to appear even previous I cheched "Don't ask again before sending requests to Test user and rand user".

Is sending apprequests only available through fb.ui and no POST method (and if post method exist - example appreciated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook app requests are not available via POST, only the plugin.  If the frictionless requests are not working, I would [log a bug with Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs).